# Java Serialization of Objects behind Interfaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, serialization, jackson

I have the following setup:

`public interface I{ public String getIprop();}`

`class A implements I{
public String a = "a";
public String getIprop(){return "i";}`

`class B implements I{
public String b = "b";
public String getIprop(){return "i";}`

`List<I> myObjects = new List<I>();
myObjects.add(new A());
myObjects.add(new B());`

myObjets should be passed back as a http response. (serialized)
With Jackson 1.x, everything was fine: the serialized return String had both objects of A and B although i serialized only their interfaces. The first object contained the a member and the i member. The second Object contained the b member and also the i member.

Now, with jackson 2.x, the serialization contains only the interfaces of my objects: Two objects wich both only contain the i-member.

Can s/o explain this behavior? How can i get the old behavoir with jackson 2 ?

Comment: What happens when you make the fields private, and provide a getter for them?

Comment: In the original, i did it in your way. Just wrote it down more compact.

Comment: Well, don't do that. Post the actual code that reproduces the problem. Otherwise, we'll provide explanations for code that isn't the actual code, and which will thus be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is it in jackson 1.x, but for jackson 2.x you have to add the type resolver in the mapper, something like:

```
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
```

or in the class, like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo
(
         use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
         include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
)
public interface I{ public String getIprop();}
```